# How to write every time to a new row of data table?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview, datatable

How can i insert each time a diffrent row in datatable?
The data table is used in a dataGridView to write a log. I need each time to write in a diffrent line (row) in the datatable, when I can't know how many rows I need in runtime.
Another thing; the datatable is loaded from a XML file, so there might be already rows in the data table.

What can i do? (in short, I always write in the same row) in C#

EDIT:
here is the code:

From some reason, the DateGridView isonly having one row(This is a method that activated in a click of a button)

```
public void gridStart(string i, string b, string c)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();//empty table with no schema
            DataColumn colContactID = new DataColumn("Date", typeof(string));
            DataColumn colContactName = new DataColumn("Caller", typeof(string));
            DataColumn colResult = new DataColumn("Result", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add(colContactID);
            dt.Columns.Add(colContactName);
            dt.Columns.Add(colResult);
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
            row["Date"] = i;
            row["Caller"] = b;
            row["Result"] = c;
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

Comment: Not sure if I understand the question correctly, but why can't you add a new row to the datatable when you need to?

Comment: ther are you binding this table to your datagrid and how are you trying to add other rows?

Comment: I tried adding other rows, same syntax, diffrent names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to Use [DataTable.NewRow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.newrow.aspx).  There are several samples on that MSDN page.  If you have more questions please provide some sample code to your answer.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.DataSource = MyDataTable;
}

private string _fileName = "MyCache.xml";

private DataTable _myDataTable;
public DataTable MyDataTable
{
    get
    {
        if (_myDataTable == null)
        {
            _myDataTable = new DataTable();
            if (File.Exists(_fileName))
                _myDataTable.ReadXml(_fileName);
            else
                InitDataTable(_myDataTable);
        }
        return _myDataTable;
    }
}

private void InitDataTable(DataTable table)
{
    table.TableName = "MyTable";
    table.Columns.Add("Date", typeof(DateTime));
    table.Columns.Add("Caller", typeof(string));
    table.Columns.Add("Result", typeof(string));
}

// Have your add code call this method!
private void AddValue(DateTime date, string caller, string result)
{
    var row = MyDataTable.NewRow();
    row["Date"] = date;
    row["Caller"] = caller;
    row["Result"] = result;
    MyDataTable.Rows.Add(row);
}

protected override void OnClosed(EventArgs e)
{
    if (_myDataTable != null)
        _myDataTable.WriteXml(_fileName,  XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
    base.OnClosed(e);
}
```

Comment: @Gilad, I added a little more than you were asking for but I hope it helps.  You could also pass in the table you want to add the row to as a parameter to the `AddValue(...)` method.

Comment: Compiler does not recognize "File.Exists"
On what namespace should i use?

Answer (score 1):

If it is bound to a data source, you need to first get the data source,

```
// Assuming it's a DataTable
DataTable dt = ((DataTable)myDataGridView.DataSource);
```

insert rows to your data source (like what your method is doing in your post), then tell the view to refresh its contents.

So maybe something like this would work:

```
public void gridStart()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    DataColumn colContactID = new DataColumn("Date", typeof(string));
    DataColumn colContactName = new DataColumn("Caller", typeof(string));
    DataColumn colResult = new DataColumn("Result", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add(colContactID);
    dt.Columns.Add(colContactName);
    dt.Columns.Add(colResult);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    // Call method to insert values.
}
```

to start up the grid, and:

```
public void gridInsert(string i, string b, string c)
{
    DataTable dt = (DataTable)myDataGridView.DataSource; 
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
    row["Date"] = i;
    row["Caller"] = b;
    row["Result"] = c;
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
    // Call another method to refresh grid view.
}
```

to call when you want to insert data to your DataTable.

Comment: That's what i did, it isn't working. Maybe you  can tell me if my code is wrong?

Comment: I just edited my answer. It would be easier to know if your DataGridView is binded to a data source like a DataTable.

Comment: Yes, it is: dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    DataTable tb = new DataTable();
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("table");
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("NR", Type.GetType("System.Int32")));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Dihname", Type.GetType("System.String")));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("ing", Type.GetType("System.String")));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Cost", Type.GetType("System.String")));
        Session["ss"] = dt;
    }
    protected void LinkButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         tb = (DataTable)Session["ss"];
         DataRow r1 = tb.NewRow();
         r1[0] = ViewState["dishid"].ToString();
         r1[1] = ViewState["dishname"];
         r1[3] = Label3.Text;
         tb.Rows.Add(r1);
         DataList5.DataSource = tb;
         DataList5.DataBind();
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, thank you . . . Although a bit late. Anyway, I wasn't using ASP.NET